# Is there a way to resize the visual table in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to use MySQL workbench to edit table fields for a database that I am working on, and the size of the table is essentially unreadable on my Mac. I wasn't sure if this is just an issue with using MySQL Workbench on a Mac, or if there is a way for me to actually make this readable.

To give you an idea of what I am trying to work with :
[The table is scaled down a lot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJmVm.jpg)

I'm not very familiar with the MySQL Workbench and am trying to learn its uses to up my efficiency when working with MySQL. I've tried searching for settings that could help change this but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!